# DirectShow memory leak C#

Tags: c#, directshow

There is a issue when allocate and release a CLSID, I use DirectShow for my USB camera and after 30000 instances the memory grow with 1 MB at 1000 instances.

The problem happens because de CLSID object isn't release correct, can you make a suggestion for that release.

```
int i = 0;
int steps = 30000;
do
{
    Guid filterGraph = new Guid(0xE436EBB3, 0x524F, 0x11CE, 0x9F, 0x53, 0x00, 0x20, 0xAF, 0x0B, 0xA7, 0x70);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(filterGraph));
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
    obj = null;

    i++;
    Marshal.CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(10);
    GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    string str = string.Format("Test nr {0}/{1}, mem = {2} Mbytes", i, steps,
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024.0 / 1024.0);
    Console.WriteLine(str);

} while (i < steps);
```

Comment: At first it is 37MB, and after 1000 become 38MB.

Comment: And after 5000? 10000?

Comment: Probably 40 and 50

Comment: Yes, of course, I written that memory is grow with 1MB every 1000 steps.

Comment: Oddly that is not what I see when I run your code (I see it sitting quite stably around 21MB on Windows 10, .NET Framework 4.7). What OS are you running on? What version of the .NET Framework? Have you tried on a co-worker's machine and verified the same behaviour there?

Comment: I use this snipped code on Windows 8.1 X64 and .net framework 4, could you tell me when it become stably? after 1000, 2000, steps?

Comment: Basically straight away.

Comment: I have same behavior on Windows 10